# Fuse OSGI + Spring JDBC issue

Tags: java, spring-jdbc, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi

I am new to OSGI development. I want to insert records to DB using Spring JDBC in Fuse server. I developed standalone SpringJDBC code, it is working good. I have converted to blueprint standard. while installing package in Fuse server, I am getting below mentioned error. I hope that Spring jars are not available in Fuse server. please help me to fix this and appreciate any sample tutorial or code.

**Server : Jboss Fuse 6.2.1**

*Error :*

```
**Error executing command: Error installing bundles:
  Unable to start bundle file:My repositorypath/myapplication.jar Unresolved constraint in bundle homeloan [302]: Unable to resolve 302.0: missing requirement [302.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.jdbc.core)**
```

POM Configuration

```
<!-- to generate the MANIFEST-FILE of the bundle -->
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.7</version>
     <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <instructions>
         <Bundle-SymbolicName>homeloan</Bundle-SymbolicName>
        <Private-Package>org.blogdemo.homeloan.*</Private-Package>
        <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
        </instructions>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

*MANIFAEST*

```
**DynamicImport-Package: *
Export-Package: org.blogdemo.homeloan.model;uses:="javax.xml.bind.annota
 tion";version="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT",org.blogdemo.homeloan.processor;uses:="o
 rg.blogdemo.homeloan.model,org.apache.camel,javax.sql,org.springframewo
 rk.jdbc.core";version="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT"
Import-Package: javax.sql,javax.xml.bind.annotation,org.apache.activemq.
 camel.component;version="[5.9,6)",org.apache.camel;version="[2.12,3)",o
 rg.osgi.service.blueprint;version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)",org.springframework.j
 dbc.core,org.springframework.jdbc.datasource
Tool: Bnd-1.50.0**
```

*blueprint.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

    <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61617" />
        <property name="userName" value="admin" />
        <property name="password" value="admin" />
    </bean>


 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    >
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/c:/temp/db/FAQ/doldb;create=true"/>
 </bean>


    <bean id="myProcessor" class="org.blogdemo.homeloan.processor.MyProcessor">
    <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

From JBoss Fuse console, type

```
features:install spring-jdbc
```

this will install the required packages. A quick check with

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root> exports | grep springframework.jdbc
    276 org.springframework.jdbc; version=3.2.12.RELEASE
    276 org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple; version=3.2.12.RELEASE
    276 org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam; version=3.2.12.RELEASE
    ....
```

will tell you that the bundle 276 is exporting such packages. (the bundle id number may vary in your installation)

If you need some other library, check with `features:list` command, it may already be distribuited as a feature.

Answer (score 0):

You would require to install required dependencies.

```
features:install camel-sql 
features:install camel-jdbc
```

I see User name and password is missing as well.
I did similar things with Oracle .

```
<bean id="oracleConnectionCacheProperties" class="java.util.Properties">
    <argument>
        <props>
            <prop key="MinLimit" value="${database.connectionCache.minLimit}" />
            <prop key="MaxLimit" value="${database.connectionCache.maxLimit}" />
            <prop key="ValidateConnection" value="${database.connectionCache.validateConnection}" />
            <prop key="InactivityTimeout" value="${database.connectionCache.inactivityTimeout}" />
        </props>
    </argument>
</bean>

<bean id="oracleInstance" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="URL" value="${oracleDataSource.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true" /> 
    <property name="connectionCacheProperties" ref="oracleConnectionCacheProperties" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlComponentInstance" class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleInstance" />
</bean>
```

Also you should check your location spaces.

```
    xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd
   http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0 http://aries.apache.org/schemas/blueprint-cm/blueprint-cm-1.0.0.xsd">
```